# Linear programming with approximate arithmetic

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, linear-programming, computational-complexity, numerical-optimization

One of the big achievements since the 80s is the solution of linear programs, e.g., by barrier method. For example, to solve

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c^T x\\ \text{subject to} & Ax \leq b\end{array}$$

one instead minimizes

$$F(x) = tc^Tx - \sum_{k=1}^m \log([b-Ax]_k)$$

for given $t > 0$ to obtain the central path $x^*(t)$, and then you follow it as $t \to \infty$ by damped Newton steps. The computational complexity is well-understood, and loosely speaking, it will take $O(\sqrt{m}\log (m\epsilon))$ damped Newton steps to reach duality gap $O(\epsilon)$.

I want to replace all arithmetic operations with (very) approximate ones, because my $m$, and the dimension $n$ of $x$, are both mind-bogglingly large. The quantities $c^Tx$ and $\log(b-Ax)$ will be computed very roughly, and similarly for the gradient and Hessian of $F$. This is for high-dimensional PDEs, and I'm considering using hierarchical Tucker or tensor trains to approximate everything, so the errors are far from machine accuracy.

But nevermind the tensor stuff, do we have any idea what happens when arithmetic operations are (very) inexact in linear programming? Specifically, how does it affect convergence, and can we still estimate the number of (now approximate) Newton steps?

I've tried to google for various combinations of "linear programming inexact arithmetic" but I find nothing. At first blush, it seems to be a can of worms because even feasibility $Ax \leq b$ is hard to decide for given $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "I want to replace all arithmetic operations with (very) approximate ones" part?

Comment: Linear programming is almost always done with floating-point arithmetic which is subject to roundoff error, so this should be "well-known".

Comment: A Google search brings up [Hua Wei's thesis](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/h3wei2006thesis.pdf) "Numerical Stability in Linear Programming and Semidefinite Programming" which seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks for Hua Wei's thesis, it is relevant and I will read it. I have read it diagonally and it looks like it focuses on the case where the errors are O(u), where u=1e-16 is the machine epsilon. I write carefully now to say that, often when one focuses on the roundoff error, one can make certain simplifications (e.g. neglecting an O(u^2) term) that are more problematic in the large-error regime. I'm interested in the situation where calculations could have something like 30% error. With this tensor approximation stuff, you can detect large errors and increase the accuracy adaptively.

Comment: Sketching perhaps? http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/iitKanpurCourse.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the Sketching link.